# Link ancora com download de arquivo

Tags: php, html, ancora

Preciso fazer algo simples, mas que não estou conseguindo.

```
<div class="txt-center">
<a href="software/programa.exe#final">Solicite agora</a>
</div>
```

Tentei fazer algo simples, mas não funciona.
Um link com download a um arquivo para donwload, e após o download levar ao ancora, que a página do passo-a-passo de como instalar o arquivo. Como é uma unica pagina, somente levar a ancora.

Tentei utilizar

Alguém poderia me ajudar, para ser coisa simples.

Talvez um javascript, ou PHP para isso?

Direto no HTML não tem como?

Agradeço

Comment: `<a href="software/programa.exe" onClick='scrollTo(0,0)'>Solicite agora</a>`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque no atributo `href` da tag `a` o link do arquivo a ser baixado:

HTML:

```
<div class="txt-center">
<a id="anchor" href="https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin">Solicite agora</a>
</div>

<a id="target">Target...</a>
```

No Javascript:

Basta fazer as referências as tags do HTML e no clique do download chamar `.scrollIntoView` da tag que você deseja dar scroll.

```
var a = document.getElementById('anchor');
var elementoAlvo = document.getElementById('target');

a.onclick = function() { elementoAlvo.scrollIntoView(); };
```

Comment: Obrigado -  Resolvido